# Elementtree and xsd sequences

Tags: python, xml, xsd, elementtree

I'm currently writing a code generator that produces [PLCOpen XML files](http://www.plcopen.org/pages/tc6_xml/). The Schema uses sequences in some places. The code generator uses `ElementTree` because of its simple interface. However, I can't find a way to make `ElementTree` respect the sequence; in fact, the children of an `Element` are always printed in canonical order. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

The method `ElementTree.append` that I used does not seem to keep the elements ordered. Using `ElementTree.insert`, however, solved the issue.